# Conflicting getter definitions for property "node" in Jackson

Tags: jackson

I am getting

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "node": org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.model.NodePointer#isNode(0 params) vs org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.model.NodePointer#getNode(0 params) (through reference chain: org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.JXPathContextReferenceImpl["namespaceResolver"]->org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.NamespaceResolver["namespaceContextPointer"])

I tried to use the Mixin solutions provided on stackoverflow but for my case, I am getting confused as to how to setup Mixin for NodePointer, which is a jxpath class and not my own.

Please help.

Comment: Use @JsonIgnore on one of the conflicting methods

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable detection of "is-getters" altogether through `ObjectMapper`, using `setVisibility()` (check javadoc for arguments, usage).